# what is "NOCAT" in Event Trace Sessions in Windows 11 22h2 and how to prevent creation of it in every boot

Tags: windows, event-log, performance-monitor, windows-11-v22h2

**logman query "NOCAT" -ets**:

```
Name:                 NOCAT
Status:               Running
Root Path:            %systemdrive%\PerfLogs\Admin
Segment:              Off
Schedules:            On

Name:                 NOCAT\NOCAT
Type:                 Trace
Append:               Off
Circular:             Off
Overwrite:            Off
Buffer Size:          64
Buffers Lost:         0
Buffers Written:      0
Buffer Flush Timer:   1
Clock Type:           Performance
File Mode:            Real-time

Provider:
Name:                 {10DE00F0-50FE-4D0E-A83D-BAE3F58C94AA}
Provider Guid:        {10DE00F0-50FE-4D0E-A83D-BAE3F58C94AA}
Level:                5
KeywordsAll:          0x0
KeywordsAny:          0x20000
Properties:           64
Filter Type:          0
```

**Performance Monitor:**
https://lookimg.com/images/2023/09/29/QeQor3.png

**NOCAT xml template:**
https://pastebin.com/Rt88Gmxv

Comment: Please see:  https://flylib.com/books/en/2.434.1/hack_74_capture_wireless_users_with_nocatauth.html  .  This looks like it belongs to you. I do not see NOCAT in Services on my machines.

Comment: @John Thanks for your reply, I'm no expert in network stuff, but I didn't install anything unusual, I checked everything with Sysinternals Autoruns and VirusTotal, again nothing malicious, I even disabled/removed some programs (eg "Simple Wall", Samsung drivers, etc.)

Comment: I have not seen NOCAT and so I am not able to help you further.  Try a full regular and full OFFLINE scan with Windows Defender and see if that uncovers something

Comment: Try searching Registry for `10DE00F0-50FE-4D0E-A83D-BAE3F58C94AA` for more info.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Already tried, nothing was found